# Rails Installing jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I wanted to install jQuery UI, in order to do that I coded this:
Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
```

/app/assets/javascipts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.draggable
//= require jquery.ui.droppable
//= require jquery.ui.resizable
```

I don't want any jQuery styling so I didn't include any css files in the manifest. I only want these 3 interactions to be include.

After I had run: bundle install and bundle update commands, and restarted server, I got following error:

```
 couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.draggable' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /old-time-turtle-app/app/assets/fonts
  /old-time-turtle-app/app/assets/images
  /old-time-turtle-app/app/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/app/assets/stylesheets
  /old-time-turtle-app/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/browser-timezone-rails-1.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jstz-rails3-plus-1.0.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/js_cookie_rails-2.1.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/browser-timezone-rails-1.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nprogress-rails-0.2.0.2/app/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nprogress-rails-0.2.0.2/app/assets/stylesheets
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/chartkick-2.2.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/chartkick-2.2.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.4.0/app/assets/images
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.4.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.4.0/app/assets/media
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/images
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/stylesheets
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.5/lib/assets/compiled
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.3/lib/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/app/assets/fonts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/fonts
  /old-time-turtle-app/.gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/images
```

It seems that it looks for these files and doesn't find them, do I need to include the .js files manually ?

Comment: what is your rails version ?

Comment: Rails 5.0.5
And I'm working in docker.

Comment: try changing `jquery.ui.draggable` to `jquery-ui/widgets/draggable`. The path have changed for `jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1` and above.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!

Comment: I have placed the answer below, please accept it so it will be useful for people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path have changed for `jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1` and above. Refer [here](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui/widgets)

Change `jquery.ui.draggable` to `jquery-ui/widgets/draggable` in **application.js**.